# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported. Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, freemarker, http-status-code-405

I have Spring Security with Spring MVC. When I try to sign up, it is giving me 405 'POST' not supported. I have disabled csrf token in security config. Let me know where did I go wrong?

My login page:

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="error" type="java.util.Optional<String>" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav role="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<h1>Log in</h1>

<p>You can use: demo@localhost / demo</p>

<form role="form" action="/login" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autofocus/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me"/>
</div>
<button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Authorization is handled by LoginController:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
}
}
```

Here is my Spring Security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe().and().csrf().disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is easy to solve, you are getting HTTP status 405 which means (from wiki):

> A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

You trying to HTTP POST a form to a handler which handles GET requests.

**Just change this:**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
}
}
```

**To this:**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
}
}
```