# Form Authentication with wrong credentials leads to HTTP 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I have a Spring web application which should be protected by Form Authentication (*I cannot use Spring Security for some reasons*).

If I request a protected resource I will be redirected to the login form and can enter the credentials. When the credentials are correct, I will be redirected to the requestet resource. Everything like it should be.

[image: See Network Screenshot]

But when I enter wrong credentials I get a `HTTP 405` message, not the error page. **Why?**

[image: See Network Screenshot]

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test/auth/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

**login.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Please type in your user name and password</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" width="40"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**loginerror.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

error!

</body>
</html>
```

**Log**

```
WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-79] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

**Controller**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        printAuth();
        return "test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testAuth() {
        printAuth();
        return "testAuth";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/test2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testAuth2() {
        printAuth();
        return "testAuth2";
    }

    private void printAuth() {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        LOG.debug("Request: " + request);
        LOG.debug("Principal: " + principal);
        LOG.debug("Principal name :" + principal.getName());
        LOG.debug("User in Role 'users': " + request.isUserInRole("users"));
    }

}
```

**Update**:

I tried the same authentication with a spimple "non Spring" application and it works fine. So I assume that the Spring servlet "catches" the request somehow. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Added controller code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I assumed in my update the Spring servlet is responsible for this problem. Therefore I had to make shure that an another servlet serves the login pages instead of the Spring servlet.

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/classes/static/login/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test/auth/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/classes/static/login/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/classes/static/login/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Hi there. What is the default servlet? Is it defined somewhere? I have the following error in the server's logs: The servlet default is referenced in servlet-mapping /WEB-INF/classes/stati
c/* but not defined in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and all the information I found is, that the servlet being called does not implement a doPost() method. But hey, that j_security_check URL is not a servlet I created, it is the tomcat provided servlet!?!?!?

Wrong! It is **the error page that must have a doPost() method**.

Thinking about it, it makes sense.
The user opens any protected page. Tomcat serves the login form under the requested URL.
The user types in a wrong user/pwd and the data is posted into the j_security_check servlet. Because of the wrong credentials, it serves under this URL the error page - but cannot.

Comment: And what was your solution to the issue?

Comment: The error page must have a doPost() method.
In the web.xml you specify a login page and an error page, both are servlets likely. If they are, the error page servlet must have a doPost method implemented.

Answer (score -1):

From wiki:

> **405 Method Not Allowed:** A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

All you have to do is to change your controller `RequestMethod` from `GET` to `POST`

You can't Post an HTTP form + try to handle it using GET method.

something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test() {
      ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testAuth() {
      ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/test2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testAuth2() {
       ...
    }

}
```

**According to *your* image:**

[image]

You are obviously trying to POST your form to this URL: ***/test/auth***

And according to your controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testAuth() {
    printAuth();
    return "testAuth";
}
```

You are using `GET` and it's wrong to do, Try to change it to POST.

Comment: The POST should not go to the controller. The POST is for authentication to 'j_security_check'. You can see it on the screenshots. The first one works although the request is the same. The only difference are the wrong credentials.

Comment: No. Because the POST **should not** go to the controller. The POST is from the login form: `<form method="post" action="j_security_check">`. This URL is a redirect from server, because the resource `/test/auth/test` is secured (see `web.xml`). Eventually my whole application should be secured and I can not change every controller to POST.

Comment: It is just basic HTTP understanding, Just try it, best of luck :-)

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388609/http-status-405-request-method-post-not-supported-spring-security/44397027#44397027     and here: https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/http-status-405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url-servlet/

Comment: I know the difference between GET and POST. The question/answer you mention is a different problem. I **do not** use Spring Security like I wrote above. [I use the Java EE 6 standard](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146077/discussion-between-deve-and-moshe-arad).